# Space over the abstract title

Tags: spacing, abstract

I am using the following code to generate a single page with the abstract:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pagesize, twoside, openright, 11pt, BCOR=4mm, DIV=11, chapterprefix, appendixprefix, headlines=1.1, footlines=1.1, headsepline, numbers=noenddot, headings=normal, abstract=true, final]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
abstract text
\end {abstract}
\end{document}
```

I get a page with the centered title "abstract" and then the "abstract text" - so far so good.
But the top margin/space before the title "abstract" is set is too high for me - How can I reduce this maring (not the space between the tilte and the text of the abstract, the space over the title)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for giving a minimal document!  If you add the class option `titlepage=false` I think you will get what you want.